# How do I write a function in F# that can be called from Excel and which will take a range as input and output an array into the ssheet?

Tags: arrays, f#, excel-formula, excel-addins, excel-dna

I understand how to do this in C# and I can create AddIns using Excel DNA. I can't figure out the F# syntax to enable a function, f, which, for sake of simplicity, does something like f(x)= 2D array of dimension [2,2] containing x at all 4 values. So I'd call f from excel taking an input from a cell, and it would return the 2x2 array.  (I will be doing more complex things here - but If I can understand that simple case I'll be fine).  Help greatly appreciated!

My attempt at creating an F# function looks like this:

```ml
let array2D : int [,] = Array2D.zeroCreate 20 20
let g x = array2D
```

The problem I'm having is that this doesn't appear as a function in the excel dropdown under the xla name.

Working C# Example:

```cs
public static double[,] arraytoexcel(int N) 
{ 
    double[,] RetArray = new double[N, N]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) { 
            RetArray[i, j] = N; 
        } 
    } 
    return RetArray; 
}
```

Comment: Can you say a bit more where you are struggling? There are several F# examples on the ExcelDNA homepage.

Comment: thanks for responding.  I am very new to F#.  I have written:
let g x = array2D  where  let array2D : int [,] = Array2D.zeroCreate 20 20
as an attempt to get an array output into excel

Comment: And it doesn't work, because?..

Comment: I obviously didn't have the 'where' in there.  I was trying to start a new line.  so the the 2 'Let's are separate lines.

Comment: it doesn't appear as a function in the excel dropdown under the xla name

Comment: whereas something like let g x = x* x does

Comment: I think you are more likely to get an answer if you can post working C# version and optionally the F# attempt so that someone can attempt to convert it

Comment: I think int[,] arrays aren't supported by Excel-DNA. Either return a double[,] array or an object[,] array

Comment: public static double[,] arraytoexcel(int N)
        {
            double[,] RetArray = new double[N, N];

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    RetArray[i, j] = N;
                }
            }

            return RetArray;
        }

Comment: sorry, I clearly can't post comments very well (I'm new to stackoverflow).  My code above hasn't appeared as I intended. Let me try the suggestion around int.  thanks for your help

Comment: Its usually best to add examples to the original question.

Comment: @henjo I've updated the question.  Its best to include: your intent, what you've tried and any other relevant details in the original question.

Comment: It seems, you searching something like that  `let arraytoexcel n = Array2D.create n n n`

Comment: @henjo: I'd bet you missed some ExcelDNA attributes on your functions. Your working C# example - are you sure there weren't any attributes on the method? Please post those, and also where you placed your attributes on the F# functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
let calculateCellContents size x y = float (y * size + x) // Whatever math you need

let mkArray size = Array2D.init size size (calculateCellContents size)
```

Note that `calculateCellContents` returns a *float* (the F# name for a C# `double`), not an int. Your C# example had the function returning an array of `double` values, and if XLA is looking for functions with that signature (returning an array of floats), then that might be one possible reason it's not showing up.

Now, if that doesn't solve the "this doesn't appear as a function in the excel dropdown" problem, there are two other possibilities I've thought of. First, if you're supposed to set an attribute on the function for the Excel dropdown to be able to find it, then the syntax is `[<AttributeName>]`. E.g.:

```
let calculateCellContents size x y = float (y * size + x) // Whatever math you need

[<ExcelFunction(Description="Make a simple array")>]
let mkArray size = Array2D.init size size (calculateCellContents size)
```

Second, it might be that you have to change the type of the function. F# functions have the type `FSharpFunc`, and it's entirely possible that XLA is looking for a `Func` rather than an `FSharpFunc`. You can convert between them by creating a new `System.Func` object from the F# function:

```
let calculateCellContents size x y = float (y * size + x) // Whatever math you need

let mkArray size = Array2D.init size size (calculateCellContents size)

let mkArrayVisibleFromExcel = new System.Func<int,float>(mkArray)
```

Or possibly:

```
[<ExcelFunction(Description="Make a simple array")>]
let mkArrayVisibleFromExcel = new System.Func<int,float>(mkArray)
```

If that doesn't work, try changing `mkArray` to take a `float` argument, and changing the call to `Array2D.init` accordingly:

```
let calculateCellContents sizeF x y = float y * sizeF + float x // Whatever math you need

let mkArray (sizeF:float) = 
    Array2D.init (int sizeF) (int sizeF) (calculateCellContents sizeF)

[<ExcelFunction(Description="Make a simple array")>]
let mkArrayVisibleFromExcel = new System.Func<float,float>(mkArray)
```

If none of those work to make your function visible in Excel's XLA dropdown, then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: BTW, now that I've seen the [ExcelDNA homepage](https://excel-dna.net/) and the examples there, I think that you need to add the `ExcelFunction` attribute to your code, and that *might* be all that was missing. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: The attributes are optional. Your initial `mkArray` function has a weird signature - you want it to be `int -> float[,]` (the calculateCellContents is not a good initializer for Array2D.init) as in the second snippet. The value you want exported to Excel must be a normal .NET method, not a `Func` or `FastFunc` delegate (function pointer). So everything after "Second, ..." will just cause confusion.

Comment: @Govert - Thanks for the comment about the first `mkArray` function: it was an accidental mistake in editing (I got all the examples except the first one), which I've now fixed thanks to your pointing it out. As for the rest, I've never used ExcelDNA so I'm just guessing at answers. You can probably explain it better than I can, so I'd appreciate if you could post your own answer to show the OP (and me, for that matter) how to do what ExcelDNA is expecting in F#. Because from what you said about it expecting a normal .Net method, I'd have thought the OP's original coude would have worked.

Comment: thanks so much for the illuminating example - this works.  There was no need to produce any Excel attributes.  The initial suggestion from rmunn works.  I don't understand the criticism of the weird signature.  What are the ramifications of this?

Comment: @henjo - I had created a `calculateCellContents` function that takes a `size` parameter, and forgotten to supply it. Which means that instead of a function that takes two index parameters `x` and `y` (that is, a function of type `int -> int -> float`, I was passing an `int -> int -> int -> float` function to `Array2D.init`, and that's the wrong type signature. Before I corrected it, my code would not have compiled. If any of that didn't make sense to you, then https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/function-signatures/ will explain it better than I can in a short comment.

Comment: Correction: It *would* have compiled, but it would have produced an array of `int -> float` functions rather than the simple array of `float`s that Excel wanted. Which is why Govert called it a "weird" signature. If that, too, made no sense to you, then you probably need to read this entire series of articles: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/thinking-functionally-intro/. Start with the first one, and read all the way through. The function signatures article I linked earlier is the ninth one there, and the fifth one on Currying will be especially necessary for you to understand.

Comment: marvelous - thanks.  This is a great community.  I hope to be able to help people out like this at some point in the distant future!